# WPF bind DataGrid combo box selected item to datacontext of selected DataGridRow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn combobox that binds to a separate ItemsSource It seems by binding this combobox to another source it changes the DataContext.

So I'm having issues binding the value of the selected item in the combobox to the DataContext of the selected row in the DataGrid.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorldDataList}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorldData}">           
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}},Path=DataContext.Countries}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem.Country}" 
                          SelectedIndex="0"/>  
            </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
class WorldDataViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<WorldData> _worldDataList = new ObservableCollection<WorldData>();
    public ObservableCollection<WorldData> WorldDataList
    {
        get { return _worldDataList; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _worldDataList, value);
        }
    }

    public List<string> Countries {get;set;}

    private WorldData worldData;
    private WorldData SelectedWorldData
    {
        get{return worldData;}
        set
        {
            Set(ref worldData, value);
        }
    }
}

class WorldData : ObservableObject
{
    private string country;
    public string Country
    {
        get{return country;} 
        set
        {
            Set(ref country, value);
        }  
}
```

I get the exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}'
>   from type 'NamedObject' to type 'WorldData' for 'en-US' culture with
>   default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter
>   cannot convert from MS.Internal.NamedObject.    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
>   value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type
>   destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean isForward)' Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   in PresentationFramework.dll

It seems like I should use a type converter but it seems I  shouldn't do this from the very little I've been able to find on SO

I think for now I'm just going to give up and add a separate box for the combobox and bind to the selected item of the Datagrid. I don't find it as intuitive so please if you have any clever ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my full test app that save back the selected Country to the `WorldData` view model. Without the `UpdateSourceTrigger` at the `SelectedItem` it doesn't work.

```
<Window
    x:Class="ComboboxInDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="me"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorldDataList}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorldData}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                                                               AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                Path=DataContext.Countries}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Country, 
                                                                 Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboboxInDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            DataContext = new WorldDataViewModel ();
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }

    class WorldDataViewModel
    {
        public WorldDataViewModel ()
        {
            var c1 = "USA";
            var c2 = "Canada";
            var c3 = "Brasil";
            var c4 = "Brasfsdfsil";

            Countries = new List<string> ();
            Countries.Add (c1);
            Countries.Add (c2);
            Countries.Add (c3);
            Countries.Add (c4);

            _worldDataList.Add (new WorldData { Index = 1, Country = c2 });
            _worldDataList.Add (new WorldData { Index = 2, Country = c3 });
            _worldDataList.Add (new WorldData { Index = 3, Country = c4 });
        }

        private List<WorldData> _worldDataList = new List<WorldData> ();
        public List<WorldData> WorldDataList
        {
            get
            {
                return _worldDataList;
            }
            set
            {
                _worldDataList = value;

            }
        }

        public List<string> Countries { get; set; }

        private WorldData worldData;
        public WorldData SelectedWorldData
        {
            get
            {
                return worldData;
            }

            set
            {
                worldData = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class WorldData
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }

        private string country;
        public string Country
        {
            get { return country; }
            set
            {
                country = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi gomi42. Just seeing this. You were able to bind to SelectedCountry? Did you put a breakpoint in SelectedWorldData.Country to see if it actually hits when you select a country? 
I also need CanUserAddRows to be true. Thanks for your attempt though

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my first answer. Now I can set a break in `Country` and the Debugger stops there.

Comment: I forgot to mention for sure you can set `CanUserAddRows` to true. I turned it off because the new to be created row shows the Combobox which might be a bit confusing from an UX perspective. Again there is no technical restriction.

Comment: It's weird. Somehow I didn't try that. But it works, thanks. I will accept your answer. Thanks!